# Efficient calculation of entropy in spark

Tags: performance, scala, apache-spark, entropy, information-theory

Given an RDD (data), and a list of index fields to calculate entropy on.  When executing the following flow it takes approximately 5s to calculate a single entropy value on a 2MB (16k row) source.

```
def entropy(data: RDD[Array[String]], colIdx: Array[Int], count: Long): Double = { 
  println(data.toDebugString)
    data.map(r => colIdx.map(idx => r(idx)).mkString(",") -> 1)
        .reduceByKey(_ + _)
        .map(v => {
        val p = v._2.toDouble / count
        -p * scala.math.log(p) / scala.math.log(2)
      })
        .reduce((v1, v2) => v1 + v2)
}
```

The output of the debugString is as follows:

```
(entropy,MappedRDD[93] at map at Q.scala:31 (8 partitions)
  UnionRDD[72] at $plus$plus at S.scala:136 (8 partitions)
    MappedRDD[60] at map at S.scala:151 (4 partitions)
      FilteredRDD[59] at filter at S.scala:150 (4 partitions)
        MappedRDD[40] at map at S.scala:124 (4 partitions)
          MapPartitionsRDD[39] at mapPartitionsWithIndex at L.scala:356 (4 partitions)
            FilteredRDD[27] at filter at S.scala:104 (4 partitions)
              MappedRDD[8] at map at X.scala:21 (4 partitions)
                MappedRDD[6] at map at R.scala:39 (4 partitions)
                  FlatMappedRDD[5] at objectFile at F.scala:51 (4 partitions)
                    HadoopRDD[4] at objectFile at F.scala:51 (4 partitions)
    MappedRDD[68] at map at S.scala:151 (4 partitions)
      FilteredRDD[67] at filter at S.scala:150 (4 partitions)
        MappedRDD[52] at map at S.scala:124 (4 partitions)
          MapPartitionsRDD[51] at mapPartitionsWithIndex at L.scala:356 (4 partitions)
            FilteredRDD[28] at filter at S.scala:105 (4 partitions)
              MappedRDD[8] at map at X.scala:21 (4 partitions)
                MappedRDD[6] at map at R.scala:39 (4 partitions)
                  FlatMappedRDD[5] at objectFile at F.scala:51 (4 partitions)
                    HadoopRDD[4] at objectFile at F.scala:51 (4 partitions),colIdex,13,count,3922)
```

If I collect the **RDD** and **parallelize** again it takes ~150ms to calculate (which still seems high for a simple 2MB file) - and obviously creates a challenge when dealing with multiple GB data.  What am I missing to properly utilize Spark and Scala?

My original implementation (which performed even worse):

```
data.map(r => colIdx
  .map(idx => r(idx)).mkString(","))
  .groupBy(r => r)
  .map(g => g._2.size)
  .map(v => v.toDouble / count)
  .map(v => -v * scala.math.log(v) / scala.math.log(2))
  .reduce((v1, v2) => v1 + v2)
```

Comment: 5 seconds is what passes for "instantaneous" in the JVM. It may just be a few passes of serialization, deserialization and GC, and no fault of your code. Try it with more data! You have to measure this in minutes before you can tell if it's slow.

Comment: As a data point: I've seen an `sc.parallelize` stage take 4 seconds on a <100 element array on a local Spark setup. And this is with Kryo serialization, which is way faster than the default.

Comment: To be clear, I am running this multiple times over the same data (with varying colIdx values).  If the performance hit was only on the first run I would be fine, but the slow runtime is all the way through the flow (this particular routine is called 794 times in my current sample)

Comment: And I am seeing a linear impact on performance.  I tried a 2GB dataset (1M rows) and each invocation was running for dozens of minutes.  The test machine has 16cores, 32GB of ram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly it looks like there is a bug in your code, you need to handle a `p` of `0` so `-p * math.log(p) / math.log(2)` should be `if (p == 0.0) 0.0 else -p * math.log(p) / math.log(2)`.

Secondly, you can use base e, you don't really need to have a base of 2.

Anyway the reason your code is slow is likely due to having so few partitions.  You should have at least 2-4 partitions per CPU, in practice I often use more.  How many CPUs do you have?

Now what is probably taking the longest amount of time is not the entropy calculation as it's very trivial - but the `reduceByKey` which is being done on a `String` keys.  Is it possible to use some other data type?  What actually is colIdx? What exactly is r?

One final observation is your indexing each record many times with this `colIdx.map(r.apply)` ... you know this will be very slow if `r` is not of type `Array` or `IndexedSeq` ... if it's a `List` it will be O(index) as you have to traverse the list to get out the index you want.

Comment: As the code counts the unique instances of column values it is not possible for p to be 0 in the final step.

Comment: I changed the partition to 32 (testing this on a 16 core machine), however I have yet to see it use more than 200% CPU.  With that I see the calc time drop to ~2.7s.  Although I see wild swings in processing time.

I added the definition of the colId (Array[Int]) and data (RDD[Array[String]).  Which makes r an Array[String].

Comment: This is counting the unique combinations of values for the columns specified.  Currently those values are string.  Short of applying a hash (that could violate unique checks) I do not see how to improve this?

Comment: I just figured out the framework we use for controlling analysis steps is causing thread contention which is what causes the serialized processing.  This is clearly not a spark issue.  However even with the contention your insight helped shave 30% off the runtime.  Many thanks!   Now to figure out why our Akka actors are misbehaving.

Comment: If it's possible to build an index, i.e. `Map[Int, String]` then you should be able to perform the `reduceByKey` on `List[Int]` - I expect this will speed things up.  Good luck with your contention issue, I guess you could try pausing said framework to confirm your suspicions.